# How to include Image Filters plugin in project

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiimage, phonegap-plugins

I am currently attempting to use DrewDahlman's Image Filters ( https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter/tree/master/iOS ) in my project. This is apparently a Cordova/Phonegap plugin, and I do not know how to import either of these plugins into my project to make DrewDahlman's filters work. All previous attempts of finding online tutorials for getting his plugin to work, or importing Cordova/Phonegap into my project have failed.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Drew never updated the plugin to work with PhoneGap/Cordova 3.x+

There seems to be a fork where someone has attempted to do just that, but I have no idea if it is complete: https://github.com/doomboy00/ImageFilter

Comment: This. I haven't had the time to maintain this project like I would have hoped. Need to find the time to spend getting things updated :/